# Set attribute based on another attribute

Tags: django, django-models

How to set hostel choices based on gender?

Global variables

BOYS_HOSTEL_CHOICES = (...)

GIRLS_HOSTEL_CHOICES = (...)

```
class Student(models.Model):

    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    
    #...
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female')
    )

    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        choices = GENDER_CHOICES,
        verbose_name="gender",
    )


    hostel = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        choices = BOYS_HOSTEL_CHOICES if gender == 'M' # <---
                            else GIRLS_HOSTEL_CHOICES,
        default = 'some hostel'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this on the model level, unless you want to implement this as a [database constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint). But it sounds like you just want to limit the choice on the form.

Allow both choices in the model:

```
hostel = models.CharField(
    max_length=40,
    # Combine choices
    choices=BOYS_HOSTEL_CHOICES + GIRLS_HOSTEL_CHOICES,
    default='some hostel'
)
```

You can also use [Django's model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) to check the constraint on save in Python.

If you need to restrict the choices in a rendered form, the form needs to know the value of the `gender` field and can then restrict the choices on the `hostel` field.

```
from django import forms

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
# ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['hostel'].choices = BOYS_HOSTEL_CHOICES
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know superset of hostel choices then you should not set choices attribute in model, because django model validate the field choices.

Make **hostel** field as a CharField without choices attribute

```
hostel = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

In this case, you can create a **form** or **modelform** where you can set dynamic choice.

```
from django import forms

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    default_choices = [your default choices if you want]

    hostel = forms.CharField(max_length=40, choices = default_choices)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['hostel'].choices = self.get_dynamic_choice()


    def get_dynamic_choice(self):
        ''' you can set choices BOYS_HOSTEL_CHOICES or GIRLS_HOSTEL_CHOICES'''
        return choices
```

but if you want dependent dropdown means on selection of **gender** field you change the value **hostel** choice then you can implement this with the help of **javascript** or **Ajax call**

Edit:

If you don't want write javascript or ajax code then you can use **django-autocomplete-light** package.

you forward selected value of **gender** in **hostel** field and access in the **view** where you can set dynamic choices for **hostel** form field. You can also search in **hostel** field value. This package also supports queryset.

In forms.py,

```
from django import forms

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    default_choices = [your default choices if you want]

    hostel = forms.ChoiceField(max_length=40,
                             choices = default_choices,
                             widget=autocomplete.ListSelect2(url='hostel_autocomplete', forward=['gender'],))
```

In urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('hostel_autocomplete/', HostelAutocompleteView.as_view(), name='hostel_autocomplete'),
]
```

In views.py,

```
from dal import autocomplete

class HostelAutocompleteView(autocomplete.Select2ListView):

    def get_list(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return []

        # you get select gender value
        gender = self.forwarded.get('gender', None)

        if gender == 'M':
            # your BOYS_HOSTEL_CHOICE_LIST
            choice_list = ['A hostel','B hostel']
        elif gender == 'F':
            # your GIRL_HOSTEL_CHOICE_LIST
            choice_list = ['C hostel', 'D hostel']
        else:
            choice_list = []

        return choice_list
```

forward value docs link- https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form